# Caliburn.Micro and ORMs (NHibernate)

Tags: c#, wpf, nhibernate, orm, caliburn.micro

Are there any information around the net about using Caliburn.Micro with an ORM such as NHibernate, preferably under WPF.

What I'm after is information about session handling and unit of work pattern. Which ever route I go down I seem to paint myself into a corner.

The problems often arise when it comes to multi window applications, and the same type of window/view running side by side with separate instances of the same type of view model.

Answer (score 1):

There is no drawbacks in using any ORM with Caliburn since they are two strategy working to solve different problems. And as a personal consideration are both great.

Comment: I agree that there are no drawbacks per se, and that they are solving different problems. But let's say I want to tie my unit of work to the lifecycle of a window/viewmodel, how would I do that? It seems to me the viewmodel's lifecycle doesn't follow the view's (which is usually a reasonable thing).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a WPF example that uses Caliburn (not micro), Nhibernate, and Windsor.  Not exactly the same situation but it might give a clue as to how session management is being handled.

http://code.google.com/p/unhaddins/source/browse/Examples/uNHAddIns.Examples.WPF/